# tooltip does not disappear

Tags: jquery, qtip

I have a div and I want to show some contents as a tooltip whenever user hover the mouse on div and the problem is that I have a dynamic contents so I can not fix them in the attribute title:

for this purpose I found  qtip useful and I wrote my code as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#plus_entity').qtip({
    content: 'This is an active list element</br>This is an active list element',
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout',
    position: {
        corner: {
           target: 'topRight',
           tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
        }
     },
style: {
    classes: 'test'
 }
});

});
```

[image]

(I did not know how to add qtip to fiddle sorry for that but in my system it works)

Now my problem is that when mousre leave happens the tooltip box does not disappear?

Can anyone help or if you think I should use better plugin please let me know?

Comment: your html is broken. you can't put html tags inside of attributes.

Comment: Sorry I was fighting with inserting my code properly Here is the link to fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/22v2F/

Comment: You can add external resources to jsfiddle using the external resources tab on the left hand side. Just paste a public url and click the plus button. You can find cdn versions of qtip here for js and css: http://qtip2.com/download both js and css should be added to the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be a problem? Here is working example:

```
$('#plus_entity').qtip({
        content: 'This is an active list element</br>This is an active list element',
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 300
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H4aTZ/295/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fiddle code the problem in my local system was that I did not include the css file from qtip and I thought it is not neccessary so after hovering out the tool tip did not remove but now it is working

Comment: Just a quick question when I change the corner to  position: {
            corner: {
               target: 'topRight',
               tooltip: 'topRight'
            }
         } the tool tip in your fiddle code does not appear at the top .Do you have any idea?